# How to set connect URL to connect to more than 1 databases in HSQLDB

Tags: hsqldb

I've started the HSQLDB server with two databases open. i'm using the server protocol for connection i.e.
jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/portdb

portdb is just one database, how can i tweak this URL such that it connects to this and the other db?

I've been referring to hsql user guide but seems nowhere defines this

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open or connect to two databases with the same `java.sql.Connection`. Use two different connections, each with its URL.

You can have multiple schemas inside a database and access them with a single connection. See http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html

Comment: Say an application needs to access 10 distinct db, so that means somewhere in the application code, 10 distinct URLs have to be defined. That’s far too tedious. Is there a way to handle this more easily? Or this is the only way?

Comment: Added schema option.

Comment: can you please elaborate?